# Hide the cells with the value of "0" and then shift all cells up

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have data in range -D2:G61 and i am checking if the column F has zero value in it then i hide that row and cells below it will shift up.

Tried this but it's deleting the entire rows-

```
Sub Hide_rows()

    Dim Col1 As String        
        Col1 = "F"
    Dim ListBottom As String   
        ListBottom = "A61"   
    Dim FirstRow As Long       
        FirstRow = 2
    Dim HideOrGroup As String  
        HideOrGroup = "Group"       
    Dim LastRow As Long         
        LastRow = Range(ListBottom).End(xlUp).Row  

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For x = FirstRow To LastRow
        If Cells(x, Col1).Value = "0"  Then
            If HideOrGroup = "Group" Then
                Rows(x).Group
            End If
            Cells(x, Col1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next x
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Its hiding the entire row..i just want to hide from column D to G

Comment: Cells from D to G needs to be shifted up if cell F has 0 in it

Comment: You cannot hide a portion of a row. You must hide the entire row. You *can* delete a range of cells in a row and shift up but then you would lose them forever.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot hide individual cells rather we can delete them on the cost of losing them forever and shift the following cell up. This can be done in two line of code.

```
Range("D15:G15").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

If the date you are hiding is not going to be referenced in the future, you may follow this approach else there doesn't seems to be another way expect taking a back of original data.

HAPPY VBA :)